# Getting my modem to emit wifi signals for my ipad?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ipad

Been working on this for some hours. I bought a DSL-526B ADSL2/2+ Ethernet/USB Modem Router
this one here http://www.dlink.com.au/products/?pid=803
and I have windows 7, connected to the internet via ADSL-2 Ethernet. The internet works OK, but what I'm after is to get my iPad to connect to it. I was told by the guy at JB Hi Fi that this modem could spread an internet signal to wifi. Still though I cannot get any wireless signal detected on my iPad. So I'm stuck, not knowing if it's my hardware or configuration or what. Please help?

Answer (score 2):

The description of that unit makes no mention of any 802.11 capability, that is, it does not have any wireless capability.
If you want an all-in-one unit, look for something with "**wireless** router" as well as "ADSL modem" in the product name/description.  Such units do exist (I have one).
  To help confuse you, many people simply say "router" when they really mean "wireless router" (i.e. a router with a wireless access point), and make no effort to distinguish what they mean versus a plain (wired-only) "router".

Answer (score 2):

I hate to break this to you, but the guy at JB Hi Fi lied to you; that model *strictly* does wired. You will need an additional (non-DSL) router to allow your wired network to interface with wireless devices (or a completely different modem, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If (as other answers suggest) the modem only does wired, then you **still have options.**. If you have a computer that you can connect using ethernet, then as long as that computer is connected, you should be able to share your internet connection using your computer's wifi. This article shows how. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-in-windows-7.html